# Count possible combination for coins array using Backtracking

Tags: c

The problem deals with the following.

For a given array

```
int coins[2] = { 1, 2 };
```

It supposed to return `3`.
Since there's the possible combinations.

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4
1 + 1 + 2 = 4
2 + 2 = 4
```

But my function returns `5`, Any ideas why?

```
int change(int coins[], int n, int sum, int index);

int main() { 
    int coins[2] = { 1, 2 };
    int c = change(coins, 2, 4, 0);
    printf("%d", c);
}

int change(int coins[], int n, int sum, int index) {
    if (sum == 0)
        return 1;
    if (sum < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (coins[i] > sum)
            continue;
        int k = change(coins, n, sum - coins[i], index);
        if (k > -1)
            return k + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if it also counts "1+2+1" and "2+1+1" ?

Comment: I don't get the expectation clear...can you elaborate?

Comment: What did you learn when you debugged your code?

Comment: While some are skeptical about debugging, explain me how **4 out of 2** coins add up to 4(1+1+1+1). There are only two coins right? Explain Clearly.

Comment: For `sum = 0; change(coins,2,sum,0)`, I'd expect a return value of 0 and `if (sum==0)
        return 0;`.  Other code should change too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the code of line which calls your function:

```
int c = change(coins,2,4,0) - 1;
```

and try with different cases.